# How to add the cell style popup menu to my customized toolbar

Tags: cells, docked-cell

I use a customized toolbar in all of my notebooks:

[image]

I would like to add the cell style popup menu that is part of the built-in formatting toolbar to my own toolbar. A code snippit for my toolbar is shown below:

```
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
  DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[
  Grid[{{
    Button["   ", cell; 
     SO[selected, 
      Background -> Lighter[RGBColor[0, 127/255, 1], .85]], 
     Background -> Blue]
    , 
    Button["   ", cell; 
     SO[selected, Background -> RGBColor[1, 0.9, 1]], 
     Background -> RGBColor[1, 0.9, 1]]
    , 
    Button["   ", cell; SO[selected, Background -> LightBrown], 
     Background -> LightBrown]

    }}, Spacings -> {.06, 1}]]],
  "DockedCell", Background -> None]
```

How can I add a cell style selection popup control to my toolbar?

Comment: You can get the list of styles in that menu by using ``Rest@FE`Evaluate@FEPrivate`GetPopupList@"MenuListStyles"`` - from there it should be straightforward to build your menu